# State not change of toggle button

Tags: android

I have listview with toggle button when i click on toggal button and scroll down then state of the button will change to Off state
Please do the  replay

Comment: Where is the toggle button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `sharedpreference` to save the state of each toggle button and load the state from the `sharedpreference`

Like you can define a state of your toggle (which has unique id) in sharedpreference

Here in Custom adaptor defined shared preference value.

```
final ToggleButton tgl=(ToggleButton)row.findViewById(R.id.tglalertstatus);

            tgl.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                    if(isChecked)
                    {
                        SharedPreferences contact = context.getSharedPreferences(
                                "contact", 1);

                        editor = contact.edit();

                        editor.putInt("toggle"+tgl.getContentDescription().toString(), 1); // i set the content description for each toggle a unique string so it will work as a key for shared preference. 

                        editor.commit();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        SharedPreferences contact = context.getSharedPreferences(
                                "contact", 1);

                        editor = contact.edit();

                        editor.putInt("toggle"+tgl.getContentDescription().toString(), 0);//i set the content description for each toggle a unique string so it will work as a key for shared preference.

                        editor.commit();
                    }

                }
            });
```

hope this will help.