# In listview scrolling down the toggle button on status will go previous off status

Tags: android, listview, togglebutton

this is my getview method of myadapterclass

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        pos = position;

```
    ApplicationInfo entry = ai.get(position);
    String str = insatllApps.get(position);
    System.out.println("Position============"+(insatllApps.get(position)));
    //Log.d("Check>>:","size>>"+insatllApps.size());
    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list__button, null);
    t1=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    iv=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    tb1=(ToggleButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.togal);
    tb1.setOnClickListener(this);
    tb1.setTag(pos);
    tb1.setTag(R.id.togal, str);

    iv.setImageDrawable(entry.loadIcon(mPackManager));


    t1.setText(str);


            return convertView;
}
```

Comment: duplicate of the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15171742/state-not-change-of-toggle-button

Answer (score -1):

well this is the solution that works

```
     View row=null
    ApplicationInfo entry = ai.get(position);
        String str = insatllApps.get(position);
        System.out.println("Position============"+(insatllApps.get(position)));
        //Log.d("Check>>:","size>>"+insatllApps.size());
        row= mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list__button, null);
        t1=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        iv=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        tb1=(ToggleButton)row.findViewById(R.id.togal);
        tb1.setOnClickListener(this);
        tb1.setTag(pos);
        tb1.setTag(R.id.togal, str);

        iv.setImageDrawable(entry.loadIcon(mPackManager));


        t1.setText(str);

return row
```

create a new view in the getView method

Comment: how can i do that plz elobarate

Comment: the code you have posted just replace that code with the one I have posted I have made minor modifications

Comment: your problem is that you check the toggle button and when you scroll list it again change it's state right ?

Comment: ya button satatus initally OFF after i click the satus is ON  and scroll down the satus will go intial i.e OFF State